# integration with 4 branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I come across a problem of contour integration with 4 branch point. The problem came down to be equivalent to integrate $\sqrt{(x^2-1)^n(x^2-2)^m}$ over the imaginary axis. So, there are two branch points on each side of the imaginary axis and I can't find any countor which doesn't include branching problem inside and is easy to compute. I wonder whether there is any technique which can help me.

Comment: I think if you enclose 2 branch points you can still define a function on the region outside the line connecting the branch points. This permits you then to use Cauchy's integral theorem, but you have to add twice the value of the integral over the line between the branches

Comment: why does the integral converge ?

Comment: ok, you are right, the integrand was $x^{m+n}-\sqrt((x^2-1)^n(x^2-2)^m)$. The problem is I don't know how to evaluate the integral over the line between branches.